# How do you separate a list into 2 based on what is in the list?

Tags: python, list

So I was given this list.

`list = ["m2010","n1950","m1834","n993","m1490"]`

I'd like to make the code separate the list into 2, which should look something like this:

`n_list = ["n1950","n993"]`

`m_list = ["m2010","m1834","m1490"]`

Everything that starts with "n" goes in the `n_list` and "m" in the `m_list`, but I'm too clueless to do it myslef...

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried.

Comment: Use a loop that uses `startswith()` to check the first letter, and then appends the value to the appropriate list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list = ["m2010", "n1950", "m1834", "n993", "m1490"]

n_list = [item for item in list if item[0] == 'n']
m_list = [item for item in list if item[0] == 'm']
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple with list comprehension. If you want to keep the original list, and make a two copies:

```
list = ["m2010","n1950","m1834","n993","m1490"] 
n_list = [i for i in list if i.startswith("n")]
m_list = [i for i in list if i.startswith('m')]
```

If you don't need to keep the original, you can do something like this:

```
list = ["m2010","n1950","m1834","n993","m1490"] 
m_list = list
n_list = [m_list.pop(m_list.index(i)) for i in m_list if i.startswith('n')]
```

output:

```
>>> m_list
['m2010', 'm1834', 'm1490']
>>> n_list
['n1950', 'n993']
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that it'll separate them if the `m` or `n` are anywhere in the string, not just the first letter.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 Thanks, I didn't notice the requirement. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is make a dictionary where the key is the first letter of the word.

```py
list = ["m2010","n1950","m1834","n993","m1490"]

def split(x):
    d = dict()
    for word in x:
       first = word[0]
       if first in d.keys():
            d[first].append(word)
       else:
            d[first] = [word]
    return d

split_lists = split(list)
print(split_lists['m'])
print(split_lists['n'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ["m2010","n1950","m1834","n993","m1490"]
n_list = []
m_list = []

for i in list:
    if i[:1]=='m':
        m_list.append(i)
    elif i[:1]=='n':
        n_list.append(i)
print(m_list)
print(n_list)
```